# Non-clustered index creation on SQL Azure takes up insane amount of storage space

Tags: indexing, azure-sql-database

I thought that a non-clustered / logical index consisted only of pointers to the actual records.

I have a table with a clustered index on the primary key (id), a datetime, and a varchar (and a few other columns I'm not indexing).

I used the command:

```
CREATE INDEX Index_CreatedDesc_AccountAsc ON MyTable (Created desc, Account asc)
```

The table has 500 million records.  I'm watching on the Azure database metrics in real time as it creates the index (it's ran for about 1 hour 30 minutes so far).

It started at 111GB, and now the table has increased in size to 120GB.  Why is it taking up so much space if it only needs to create pointers to the physical records/data pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just pointers. In reality, Azure SQL database and SQL Server are creating a balanced tree or b-tree (more exactly a B-Plus tree) as is explained on SQL [Server Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JDMQJYC) book. B-trees start small and perfectly formed and grow nicely to enormous sizes. If you don't defragment them regulary they may get fragmented and consume more space as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dilkushp/2013/07/27/fragmentation-in-sql-azure/).